# How to store data in cache?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I created a `ViewComponent` to display a `List<Product>`, the list is valorized taken data from a `REST API` service, this is my class implementation:

```
public class ProductsViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public ProductsViewComponent(HttpClient client)
    {
        _client = client ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(client));
    }

    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(string date)
    {
       using (var response = await _client.GetAsync($"/"product/get_products/{date}"))
       {
           response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
           var products = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Product>>();
           return View(products);
       }
    }
}
```

I load the List inside an html table which is available inside the `Components` folder: `Views\Shared\Components\Products\Default.cshtml`.

In each `View` that needs to display the `Products` I did:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("Products", new { date = myDate })
```

The `REST API` is called using the `HttpClient` configured in the `Startup.cs` as following:

```
services.AddHttpClient<ProductsViewComponent>(c =>
{
    c.BaseAddress = new Uri('https://api.myservice.com');
});
```

This works well, but the main problem is each time the user reload the page or maybe go inside another View which require to display the list of products, then the app will make another `API` call.

Is possible store the list in something like a cache and prevent to call the `API` again if the date is equal than the previous date selected?

I'm learning `ASP.NET Core` so I'm not really expert on this argument.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: [Work with a distributed cache in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per microsoft documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-2.1

you can use `IMemoryCache` to cache data

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMemoryCache();

         services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    }
}
```

and create instance of `IMemoryCache`. This is an example from Microsoft documentation. You can Create another class to handle this all together and In below example this is just saving DateTime But, you can save any object in cache and when you try to read that value from cache just need to cast that object into a Type.

I will strongly recommend you go through the above documentation.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IMemoryCache _cache;

    public HomeController(IMemoryCache memoryCache)
    {
        _cache = memoryCache;
    }

    public IActionResult CacheTryGetValueSet()
    {
       DateTime cacheEntry;

       // Look for cache key.
       if (!_cache.TryGetValue(CacheKeys.Entry, out cacheEntry))
       {
           // Key not in cache, so get data.
           cacheEntry = DateTime.Now;

           // Set cache options.
           var cacheEntryOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions()
           // Keep in cache for this time, reset time if accessed.
                .SetSlidingExpiration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));

           // Save data in cache.
        _cache.Set(CacheKeys.Entry, cacheEntry, cacheEntryOptions);
      }

      return View("Cache", cacheEntry);
   }

}
```

**Update**: `CacheKeys.Entry` is a static class where all keys are defined. (Just coding standards). Please check the above documentation link.

```
public static class CacheKeys
{
   public static string Entry { get { return "_Entry"; } }
   public static string CallbackEntry { get { return "_Callback"; } }
   public static string CallbackMessage { get { return "_CallbackMessage"; } }
   public static string Parent { get { return "_Parent"; } }
   public static string Child { get { return "_Child"; } }
   public static string DependentMessage { get { return "_DependentMessage";} }
   public static string DependentCTS { get { return "_DependentCTS"; } }
   public static string Ticks { get { return "_Ticks"; } }
   public static string CancelMsg { get { return "_CancelMsg"; } }
   public static string CancelTokenSource { get { return "_CancelTokenSource";} }   
}
```

Comment: What's the difference agains `IDistributedCache`?

Comment: what is `CacheKeys.Entry`?  I cannot find it

Comment: That's not part of the framework. Most likely, it's a static class the author created to store string constants for the various keys in the cache. That keeps things DRY and prevents magic strings cropping up all over the place.

Comment: @Charanoglu please check the updated answer. and please go through the link.

Comment: @JawardSingh: it's best to just always use `IDistributedCache`. If you want to cache in memory, you can use the memory cache provider, and ASP.NET Core actually does by default, but then you can also sub in Redis, SQL Server, etc. without changing your code.

Comment: @ChrisPratt thanks, yes it does make sense to use Redis when one have to get same data from the database server. which will improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a distributed cache and so use Redis for example with a ConnectionMultiplexer.
And so foreach call you can call your redis for the cache which is implement thanks to an interface call here 'IDistributedCache'
You can find a lot of documentation to implement cache and use it. 
: [.Net framework](https://www.codeguru.com/csharp/azure/caching-implementation-with-c-using-redis-cache.html) 
[DotNet Core](https://surfingthecode.com/redis-based-distributed-cache-in-asp.net-core/)

Your controller X  :

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{itemId}")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetItemById(int eventId, [FromUri]EventTabs tabId)
    {

        ServiceResponse<ItemDto> result = await _itemDispatcher.GetItemById(itemId);

        return WrapResponse(result);
    }
```

Your dispatcher to get the item by id which use redis cache (already implement)

```
 public class ItemDispatcher : ItemDispatcher
{

    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly IDistributedCache _distributedCache; // use interface of your implementation of redis cache

    private readonly int _cacheDuration;
    private readonly bool _isCacheEnabled;

    public EventDispatcher(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IDistributedCache distCache)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;

        _distributedCache = distCache; // init cache in constructor


        _cacheDuration = _configuration.Get<int>("cache.duration"); // duration of your cache
        _isCacheEnabled = _configuration.Get<bool>("cache.isEnable"); // if the cache is enable or not
    }



     public async Task<ServiceResponse<ItemDto>> GetItemById(int id)
    {
      // Add this for each Task call
          var cacheKey = string.Empty;

            if (_isCacheEnabled)
            {
                cacheKey = CacheUtils.GetCacheKey(CacheKeys.Item, id);
                itemDto cacheResult = await _distributedCache.Get<ItemDto>(cacheKey);

                if (cacheResult != null)
                    return new ServiceResponse<Item>(cacheResult);
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
Cache["KeyName"] = VariableOrTable;  Cache.Insert("Key", VariableOrTable, null, 
Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, ts);
```